# ionic2 Acesso a câmera em uma Page

Tags: ionic2

Boa noite de tanto quebrar a cabeça, decidi postar aqui minha dúvida.

Tenho uma Page que acessa a câmera do dispositivo, porém a câmera utiliza a tela em full screen. 
Gostaria de saber se alguém já conseguiu colocar a câmera em uma Page com tela dividida. Como na foto abaixo.

Desde já agradeço.

[image: Dividir a tela do celular mostrando o texto e o que está sendo gravado.]